# An imported function no longer works after another import is done

Tags: python, namespaces, import, coding-style

So this is what I'm dealing with:

> I have a module A, where
>
> - submodule A.B contains a function called "func1"
> - submodule A.B.C contains a function called "func2"
>
> I also have a separate module B with an class C
>
> Lastly, A.B.func1 uses class C from module B, through the import statement "from B import C"

What I've learned so far is that, if I just do:

```
from A.B import func1
```

func1 will work.

However, if I were to do:

```
from A.B import func1
from A.B.C import func2
```

func1 will not work.

After digging around and trying stuff, I've found that A.B.func1's usage of C would look at func1's globals to find C (put there by its "from B import C"). However, the entry for C in the globals is overwritten when "from A.B.C import func2" is executed. Basically, the fact that I have both A.B.C and B.C is confusing the global namespace and thus causing this unexpected failure, despite that within each module the code looks correct.

However, I'm at a loss for how to prevent this from happening in the future. What naming rules/conventions should I follow to prevent something like this happening? A drastic solution might be to make sure you never have two submodules with the same name, but I would imagine with a large enough library system this may be difficult to upkeep. What does everyone else do in this situation?

Perhaps I should be using imports differently, and do something other than "from ... import ..."?

Any comments/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a simple 'import A' then calling 'A.B.func1()' and 'A.B.C.func2()'?

Comment: Can you just refactor until there are no more globals?  They are not helping things.

Comment: @max k. That would certainly work, I guess I was hoping for a solution that doesn't bring in the entirety of A's library. But then, based on what I've read so far, maybe it does that anyway?

Comment: @roippi: Not sure what you mean. I did not explicitly create those globals. They're the byproduct of (and used by) the imports.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like circular imports, which in general you need to better structure your project to avoid. If you have to do so, then you need to do a local import. On the other hand, if you have naming conflicts, the easiest thing to do is to simply:

```
import A
```

and then call the function with A.B.fun*

Comment: Would doing "import A" bring in more things than "from A.B import func1"? Or would "from A.B import func1" also bring in the entirety of A?

Also, to be more specific, in my case "A" is a Test library, so its submodules tend to match the structure of regular libs. How do people generally name their test libraries?

Comment: 1. "import A" will not bring more things than "from A.B import func1" unless you do "from A import *". 2. "from A.B import func1" will not bring the entirety of A, which means you can't do A.X. It would tell you no module named A or something to that effect because did not import A.

Comment: or something to that effect because did not import A. 3. I am sensing that your A is simply a package? Hence a directory with some python files? For example, say your project is located at ~/mypj and is on PYTHONPATH. Your A is ~/mypj/tests, your B is a module under A which is ~/mypj/tests/functional_tests.py